# Append Tags with attributes to XML with minidom

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, minidom

I am parsing a xml using minidom. What I want to achieve is find all the tags with a certain attribute and then append a new tag with different attribute value below it. For e.g

Lets say the tag is:

```
<PROPVAL ISFORMULA="N" LOCALIZABLE="false" NAME="EntDataRegion" VALUE="XYZ"/>
```

I found all tags that has attribute value `NAME = "EntReg"` . Now I want to append a tag below it.

```
<PROPVAL ISFORMULA="N" LOCALIZABLE="false" NAME="EntRoutingDataSelected" VALUE="yes"/>
```

The tag name and value will we static i.e I want to append same tag where ever the `PROPVAL` attribute `NAME` has value `EntDataRegion`.

So far I have written this and found all `PROPVAL` tags:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('test.xml')
prop_val = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('PROPVAL')
for i in prop_val:
    if i.attributes['NAME'].value == 'PB:EntDataRegion':
        print(i.attributes['VALUE'].value)
```

**Edit**

The XML structure is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MOD version="3">
<CLASS>
<CLASS COMMENT="" DEFAULTPRIORITY="50">
<PROPVAL ISFORMULA="N" LOCALIZABLE="false" NAME="EntDataRegion" VALUE="XYZ"/>
<RULE LOCALIZABLE="false"/>
<ITEM>
<PROPVAL ISFORMULA="N" LOCALIZABLE="false" NAME="HIDE" VALUE="XYZ"/>
</ITEM>
</CLASS>
<CLASS COMMENT="" DEFAULTPRIORITY="50">
<PROPVAL ISFORMULA="N" LOCALIZABLE="false" NAME="EntDataRegion" VALUE="XYZ"/>
<RULE LOCALIZABLE="false"/>
<ITEM>
<PROPVAL ISFORMULA="N" LOCALIZABLE="false" NAME="HIDE" VALUE="XYZ"/>
</ITEM>
</CLASS>
</CLASS> 
<CLASS>
<ITEM>
<PROPVAL ISFORMULA="N" LOCALIZABLE="false" NAME="EntDataRegion" VALUE="XYZ"/>
<PROPVAL ISFORMULA="N" LOCALIZABLE="false" NAME="EntRoutingDataSelected" VALUE="yes"/>
</ITEM>
</CLASS>
</MOD>
```

The xml has two tags `CLASS` and `<ITEM>` . The class tag can have item tag as child tag. But before having item as child tag it will always have a bunch of `<PROPVAL>` tags.

The idea is to insert

`<PROPVAL ISFORMULA="N" LOCALIZABLE="false" NAME="EntRoutingDataSelected" VALUE="yes"/>`

before

`<PROPVAL ISFORMULA="N" LOCALIZABLE="false" NAME="EntDataRegion" VALUE="XYZ"/>`

The issue is I am able to insert the above tag. The fact that class tag which has item tag also takes this property. Whereas I only want `ITEM` tags to have this property if they have `<PROPVAL NAME="EntDataRegion">`

This is what I have tried:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('test.xml')
prop_val = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('PROPVAL')
class_xml = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('CLASS')
item_xml = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ITEM')
newScript = xmldoc.createElement("PROPVAL")
newScript.setAttribute("ISFORMULA"  , "N")
newScript.setAttribute("LOCALIZABLE", "false")
newScript.setAttribute("NAME", "EntRoutingDataSelected")
newScript.setAttribute("VALUE", "yes")
print(newScript.toxml())

for i in range(len(class_xml)):
   item = class_xml[i]
   item_chidren = item.childNodes
   item.insertBefore(newScript, item_chidren[4])


with open('newtest.xml', 'w') as f:
    xmldoc.writexml(f)
```

Comment: Look at insertBefore: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html?highlight=setattribute#xml.dom.Node.insertBefore

Comment: Looked and tried but didn't worked. Maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What's happening when you run your second code sample, and what did you expect that would happen?

Comment: @Tomalak I have properly stated what I expect to happen and where it is going wrong

Comment: The fact that it might not working as expected is because of the hierarchy of the CLASS and ITEM tags.

Comment: The XML is not well-formed.

Comment: @mzjn The MOD tag is the root tag. As this is just a snippet from the original I forgot to close it

Comment: There are also no `</RULE>` end tags.

Comment: @mzjn I correct and tested the xml.